# CakePHP: How to define multiple success parameters when creating an AJAX-link?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have currently the problem with CakePHP that I don't know how to define multiple success parameters in an AJAX/JS-link.

Currently, that's my code I have:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->link('Firma entknüpfen', array(
        'controller' => 'contacts',
        'action' => 'unbindCompany',
        $contact['Contact']['id']
    ),
    array(
        'update' => '#success',
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#current_company')->effect('fadeOut')  
)); ?>
```

Now, I need a second 'success'-parameter/action to fade in another element, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->link('Firma entknüpfen', array(
        'controller' => 'contacts',
        'action' => 'unbindCompany',
        $contact['Contact']['id']
    ),
    array(
        'update' => '#success',
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#current_company')->effect('fadeOut')
        'success' => $this->Js->get('#assign_company')->effect('fadeIn')    
)); ?>
```

I tried to pass an array to success but this didn't work, too.
How can I realise this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

[**`JsHelper::effect()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3aeffect) returns a string, so you could simply concat the return values:

```
'success' => $this->Js->get('#current_company')->effect('fadeOut') .
             $this->Js->get('#assign_company')->effect('fadeIn')
```